# Syntax Error in Create Function

Tags: sql, mysql, function, mysql-error-1064

This is one of the more confusing functions I've attempted. The logic works within a select statement, but I can't seem to create a user-defined function.

Here's the error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'delimiter$$
>   create function `checkdate` ( 
>   p_datetimestamp varchar (6)  )  retur'
>   at line 1"

Here's the code:
(Changing a text string 'yymmdd' into date format. '100810' becomes 2010-09-01 per the logic.)

```
delimiter$$
create function `checkdate` (
 p_datetimestamp varchar (6)
 )
 returns date

begin
declare ret_val date;
set ret_val = 
   str_to_date(
 concat(
  /*Assign Year -> %y*/
    if(
    mid(p_datetimestamp,3,2) = '12',
    (left(p_datetimestamp,2) + 1),
    left(p_datetimestamp,2)
    ),
  /*Assign Month -> %m*/
    if(
    (mid(p_datetimestamp,3,2) >= '01' and mid(p_datetimestamp,3,2) <= '11'),
    concat('0', (mid(p_datetimestamp,3,2) + 1)), '01'
    ),
  /*Assign Date -> %d*/
    if(
    (mid(p_datetimestamp,5,2) >= '01' and mid(p_datetimestamp,5,2) <= '16'), '01', '17'
    ),
 ), 
    '%y%m%d');
return ret_val;
end$$
```

Comment: Ugh - this is why you correctly data type.  The time saved for the flexibility & accommodation, was lost long ago trying to fix the mess it makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rogue comma right at the end

```
DELIMITER $$

create function `checkdate` (
 p_datetimestamp varchar (6)
 )
 returns date

begin
declare ret_val date;
set ret_val = 
   str_to_date(
 concat(
  /*Assign Year -> %y*/
    if(
    mid(p_datetimestamp,3,2) = '12',
    (left(p_datetimestamp,2) + 1),
    left(p_datetimestamp,2)
    ),
  /*Assign Month -> %m*/
    if(
    (mid(p_datetimestamp,3,2) >= '01' and mid(p_datetimestamp,3,2) <= '11'),
    concat('0', (mid(p_datetimestamp,3,2) + 1)), '01'
    ),
  /*Assign Date -> %d*/
    if(
    (mid(p_datetimestamp,5,2) >= '01' and mid(p_datetimestamp,5,2) <= '16'), '01', '17'
    ) /*<-- Comma Removed from Here*/
 ), 
    '%y%m%d');
return ret_val;
end$$
```

Comment: thanks for the responses!

comma removed, still faults.

??

Comment: Works for me. Oh - One other thing I changed is adding a space so `delimiter$$` becomes `delimiter $$`

Comment: d(@*! spaces.

that was it.

thanks a ton.